# check the existence of a specific key in registry key using java?

Tags: java, registry

How to verify the existence of a specific key in registry key using java ?
Using java (runtime).

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java check that link out for a pointer in the right direction, try something, then come back and post some code :)

Comment: What do you mean with "registry key"?

Comment: What does 'not that I want' mean?